# How do I make Python 3.4 keep score of the amount of guesses made?

Tags: python, scoring

I am making a Guess the Number game in Python, and I want to make Python keep score of how many times it took you to guess the number before you got it right. How would I go about doing this? If needed, I can post my code to view. Thank you.

```
import time
import os
from random import randrange, uniform

#Difficulty - Easy
def easy():
    print ("")
    print ("Difficulty: Easy")
    print ("")
    irand = randrange(1,10)
    with open("GTN.txt", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(str(irand) + " Easy" + "\n")
    while True:
        number = input("Pick a number 1 - 10: ")
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            print("    ")
            print(number, 'is not a number, try again.')
            continue
        if number > irand:
            print("That's too high, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number < irand:
            print("That's too low, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number == irand:
            print("    ")
            print("You got it right! You won!")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(2)
            main()
            break

#Difficulty - Medium       
def medium():
    print ("")
    print ("Difficulty: Medium")
    print ("")
    irand = randrange(1,100)
    with open("GTN.txt", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(str(irand) + " Medium" + "\n")
    while True:
        number = input("Pick a number 1 - 100: ")
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            print("    ")
            print(number, 'is not a number, try again.')
            continue
        if number > irand:
            print("That's too high, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number < irand:
            print("That's too low, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number == irand:
            print("    ")
            print("You got it right! You won!")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(2)
            main()
            break

#Difficulty - Hard
def hard():
    print ("")
    print ("Difficulty: Hard")
    print ("")
    irand = randrange(1,1000)
    with open("GTN.txt", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(str(irand) + " Hard" + "\n")
    while True:
        number = input("Pick a number 1 - 1,000: ")
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            print("    ")
            print(number, 'is not a number, try again.')
            continue
        if number > irand:
            print("That's too high, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number < irand:
            print("That's too low, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number == irand:
            print("    ")
            print("You got it right! You won!")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(2)
            main()
            break

#Difficulty - Ultra
def ultra():
    print ("")
    print ("Difficulty: Ultra")
    print ("")
    irand = randrange(1,100000)
    with open("GTN.txt", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(str(irand) + " Ultra" + "\n")
    while True:
        number = input("Pick a number 1 - 100,000: ")
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            print("    ")
            print(number, 'is not a number, try again.')
            continue
        if number > irand:
            print("That's too high, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number < irand:
            print("That's too low, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number == irand:
            print("    ")
            print("You got it right! You won!")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(2)
            main()
            break

#Difficulty - Master
def master():
    print ("")
    print ("Difficulty: Master")
    print ("")
    irand = randrange(1,1000000)
    with open("GTN.txt", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(str(irand) + " Master" + "\n")
    while True:
        number = input("Pick a number 1 - 1,000,000: ")
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            print("    ")
            print(number, 'is not a number, try again.')
            continue
        if number > irand:
            print("That's too high, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number < irand:
            print("That's too low, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number == irand:
            print("    ")
            print("You got it right! You won!")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(2)
            main()
            break

#This is the MainMenu  
def main():
    time.sleep(2)
    while True:
        print ("Please select a difficulty when prompted!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[1] Easy")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[2] Medium")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[3] Hard")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[4] Ultra")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[5] Master")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[6] Exit")
        print ("")
        time.sleep(1)
        choice = input ("Please Choose: ")

        if choice == '1':
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("")
            print ("Loading game...")
            time.sleep(2)
            easy()

        elif choice == '2':
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("")
            print ("Loading game...")
            time.sleep(2)
            medium()

        elif choice == '3':
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("")
            print ("Loading game...")
            time.sleep(2)
            hard()

        elif choice == '4':
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("")
            print ("Loading game...")
            time.sleep(2)
            ultra()

        elif choice == '5':
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("")
            print ("Loading game...")
            time.sleep(2)
            master()

        elif choice == '6':
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("")
            print ("Exiting the game!")
            print ("")
            print ("3")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("2")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("1")
            time.sleep(2)
            SystemExit 

        else:
            print ("Invalid Option: Please select from those available.")
            print("")
            time.sleep(1)

print ("Welcome to GTN!")
time.sleep(2)
print ("Developed by: oysterDev")
time.sleep(2)
print ("Version 1.1.0")
print ("    ")        
main()
```

Comment: @vaultah Just added it.

Comment: You have a lot of duplication there, note the minor differences between difficulty levels, and factor them out to parameters. What have you tried for keeping track of the number of guesses?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I haven't really tried anything. I'm new to Python and haven't learned too much yet. I've been trying to figure out how to score, but I can't figure out how to. As for the duplication, I am not sure how to shrink that code.

Comment: python really encourages DRY (don't repeat yourself) philosophy. Any blocks or chunks of code that you find yourself rewriting or repeating, can and should be extracted into a function, either inline or otherwise.

Comment: What's with all the calls to `sleep`?  If I were using this game I would go crazy because it looks like it would take 15 seconds before one can even start playing.

Comment: @kartikg3 I am not sure how to do that. I am new to Python so I don't know too much yet.

Comment: @SethMMorton I had the pauses so everything just didn't get spit out immediately. It seems nicer if I do it with the sleeps. I may change it though, not sure.

Comment: Yes, it's clear that's why you added them, but I imagine it would only serve to frustrate a user that just wants to play the game.

Comment: @SethMMorton I'll probably end up changing it. I just want it to look fluid.

Answer (score 1):

@Benjamin's answer would work. But to answer your question about how to start enforcing DRY, you could do something like this:

Your whole main game code could go into this function, taking in some key parameters that define the hardness:

```
def the_game(difficulty_name, range_start, range_end):
    score = 0
    print ("")
    print ("Difficulty: %s" % difficulty_name)
    print ("")
    irand = randrange(range_start, range_end)
    with open("GTN.txt", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(str(irand) + " %s" % difficulty_name + "\n")
    while True:
        number = input("Pick a number 1 - 10: ")
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            print("    ")
            print(number, 'is not a number, try again.')
            continue
        if number > irand:
            print("That's too high, try again.")
            print("    ")
            score += 1
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number < irand:
            print("That's too low, try again.")
            print("    ")
            score += 1
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number == irand:
            print("    ")
            print("You got it right! You won!")
            print("    ")
            print("You guessed wrong " + str(score) + " times")
            time.sleep(2)
            main()
            break
```

Then you could define little functions that call the game based on the hardness level chosen by the user, like so:

```
#Difficulty - Easy
def easy():
    the_game("Easy", 1, 10)

#Difficulty - Medium       
def medium():
    the_game("Medium", 1, 100)

#Difficulty - Hard
def hard():
    the_game("Hard", 1, 1000)

#Difficulty - Ultra
def ultra():
    the_game("Ultra", 1, 100000)

#Difficulty - Master
def master():
    the_game("Master", 1, 1000000)
```

And finally, you can define the main function like so:

```
#This is the MainMenu  
def main():
    time.sleep(2)
    while True:
        print ("Please select a difficulty when prompted!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[1] Easy")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[2] Medium")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[3] Hard")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[4] Ultra")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[5] Master")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("[6] Exit")
        print ("")
        time.sleep(1)
        choice = input ("Please Choose: ")

        def show_loading_screen():
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("")
            print ("Loading game...")
            time.sleep(2)

        def show_exit_screen():
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("")
            print ("Exiting the game!")
            print ("")
            print ("3")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("2")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print ("1")
            time.sleep(2)

        if choice == '1':
            show_loading_screen()
            easy()

        elif choice == '2':
            show_loading_screen()
            medium()

        elif choice == '3':
            show_loading_screen()
            hard()

        elif choice == '4':
            show_loading_screen()
            ultra()

        elif choice == '5':
            show_loading_screen()
            master()

        elif choice == '6':
            show_exit_screen()
            SystemExit 

        else:
            print ("Invalid Option: Please select from those available.")
            print("")
            time.sleep(1)
```

You will find that we have extracted some repeating screen loading lines of code into inline functions, that we can reuse.

In the end, you can call this main function IF this Python file is being executed as a script. This is a good practice. You can do it like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("Welcome to GTN!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("Developed by: oysterDev")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("Version 1.1.0")
    print ("    ")        
    main()
```

Hopefully, this was helpful to understand how to start refactoring for DRY.

Comment: It works great :) Thanks! I also managed to get it to automatically tell me what range I have. :) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

try to make a variable named ex. "score" and add 1 to it every time they guess wrong.

this should work.

```
def easy():
score = 0
print ("")
print ("Difficulty: Easy")
print ("")
irand = randrange(1,10)
with open("GTN.txt", "a") as text_file:
    text_file.write(str(irand) + " Easy" + "\n")
while True:
    number = input("Pick a number 1 - 10: ")
    try:
        number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        print("    ")
        print(number, 'is not a number, try again.')
        continue
    if number > irand:
        print("That's too high, try again.")
        print("    ")
        score += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    elif number < irand:
        print("That's too low, try again.")
        print("    ")
        score += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    elif number == irand:
        print("    ")
        print("You got it right! You won!")
        print("    ")
        print("You guessed wrong " + str(score) + " times")
        time.sleep(2)
        main()
        break
```

hope it helps.